# TD - is a loop the right choice?

Tags: java, loops

I apologies for my poor knowledge of programming and english in advance.

So my friends and I are a creating a tower defence game as our 2nd semester project at our university. The semester is about user involvment, so we decided to create a tower defence as we can include user in a lot of things. But we have given our tower defence game a twist, we have included questions inbetween waves, which gives a reward of x amount of gold if answered correct. 
As it is right now we only have one question for each wave, and we would like to include up to 5 questions for each wave, this is done due to if people want to play it more than once, they cannot just remember the right answer from earlier. We have already made a list of questions in a text file which looks like this, example:

Which Chinese leader’s widow was sentenced to death as a member of the Gang of Four?

A: Zhou Enlai

B: Jiang Zemin

C: Mao Zedong

D: Sun Yat-Sen

3

Example done, and this is done with up to 50 questions.

And our code for reading this txt file so far looks like this:

```
public class ReadFile {

    public static void OpenFile(){
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("/save/QuestionsB.txt");
            BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            //int numberOfLines = readLines();

            for (int j=0; j < Value.numberOfQuestions; j++){
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++){

                        Value.textData[j][i] = textReader.readLine();


                }
            }

            textReader.close();
        }
         catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReadFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    public static void loadQuestions(){
        try {
        Scanner loadScanner = new Scanner(new File("save/questionFile.qreepz"));

        while (loadScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            for (int j=0; j < Value.numberOfQuestions; j++){
                for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
                        Value.textData[j][i] = loadScanner.nextLine();        
                }
            }


        }

        loadScanner.close();
        } catch (Exception e)  { } 
    }
```

My question is now, how do we create a game with 5 questions saved for eachwave, and one random is selected, I hope you know what I mean. 
I was thinking about doing some kind of if loop, but I am not sure of how to do this. I hope you can help, thank you for your time!

Comment: "some kind of if loop"?!

Comment: @mok well you knew what I ment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code to get you started. I'll leave it to you as to how and where to place it.

```
Question[] possibleQuestions = //collate your questions into an array.
Random rand = new Random();
Question thisRoundsQuestion = possibleQuestions[rand.nextInt(possibleQuestions.length)];
//offer question to user.
```

Info on `Random.nextInt()` can be [found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29).

This solution does not cover repeating questions. If you would like to never repeat a question you will either need to keep track of the Questions asked or use a `Collection` such as an `ArrayList` and `remove` Questions as you use them to make sure they're not in the pool next time around.